# Super User is not displaying my correct reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, user-profiles

My stats as seen on stackoverflow

- Super User     98 rep    5
- Stack Overflow 90 rep    10
- Programmers  1 rep  2

stats as seen on SuperUser

- Super User   98 rep  5
- Stack Overflow   80 rep  10
- Programmers  1 rep   2

Comment: the page is heavily cached

Comment: I cleared my browser cache and run ccleaner still same.

Comment: It's cached server-side to reduce the load generated by users.

Answer (score 2):

The user profile page is heavily cached **server side** and refreshed at specific intervals. Give it few [days to few weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130940/why-is-one-profile-page-showing-one-rep-while-another-profile-page-is-showing-a) to sync.